# Document function usage issue

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to do XPath on an XML file and retrieve the value based on provided key in the XSLT and have to use the result.

Below is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mm:ValueMaps
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mm="http://WCToSSFSMediationModule">

    <mm:Map name="storeIdToOrganizationCode">  
        <mm:Entry key="19658">001GB</mm:Entry>
        <mm:Entry key="11306">001CA</mm:Entry>
    </mm:Map>
</mm:ValueMaps>
```

Below is the XPath i have used in document function inside  XSLT and but my bad its not working. Could some please help me in figuring it out.

```
<xsl:variable name="actualOrganizationCode"  
              select="document(&quot;Maps.xml&quot;,&quot;mm:ValueMaps/mm:Map[@name='storeIdToOrganizationCode']/mm:Entry[@key=$storeId]/text()&quot;)"/>
```

`storeId` is a variable that hold value in XSLT which i am using in `document()` function.

FYI `Maps.xml` is located under same directory of XSLT.

Regards,

Tarak.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document()` function will return a context where you can run the XPath expression. You don't include the expression as a second argument. You should use it like this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="document('Maps.xml')/mm:ValueMaps/mm:Map[@name='storeIdToOrganizationCode']/mm:Entry[@key=$storeId]/text()"/>
```

You might also prefer to place it in a variable:

```
<xsl:variable name="$doc" select="document('Maps.xml')"/>
```

And refer to it when you wish to access any of its nodes:

```
 <xsl:value-of select="$doc/mm:ValueMaps/mm:Map[@name='storeIdToOrganizationCode']/mm:Entry[@key=$storeId]/text()" />
```

You should also register the `mm` prefix *in your stylesheet*, since the prefix used in the *source document* will not be considered by the XPath expressions in your stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks helderdarocha, I came to know wht mistake i did. Thanks a lot for solution.